# IEEE representation of binary number

Tags: floating-point, binary, ieee-754

I came across this problem that I am not able to solve.

`The IEEE short floating point representation of the binary number 1001.1011 is`

And the answer is given as `1 00000011 00110110000000000000000`.

I am not sure how the sign bit is 1. and how is exponent just `11`. should not the exponent be 127+3.

Since we will change the give to 1.0011011* 2^3.

How do we do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct.

The sign bits should be zero and the encoded exponent should be 127 + 3, which is `b10000010`.  So the correct encoding is:

```
0 10000010 00110110000000000000000
```